# Invantive Data Hub: I would like to automate the execution of SQL commands in a script

Tags: sql

I would like to use Invantive Data Hub to automate my SQL commands using a script, since I wouldn't like to execute them manually them each time.

How would I go about executing SQL commands automatically with Invantive Data Hub?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of to use these SQL commands with a script, is to pass the name of the file through parameters.

Such a command line is easily constructed by choosing `Create Data Hub Batch Script` from the `Editor` menu in the ribbon of the `Invantive Query Tool`.

[image]